# Xcode Documentation is empty

Tags: ios, xcode

See:

[image: Xcode Documentation dialog]

I should have messed up this on previous Xcode version, there shouldn't be only "Guides and Sample Code", or is this the situation for everyone??

How can I get the latest iOS documentation back?

I'm on Xcode Version 8.2 (8C38)

Answer (score 1):

You can check on **Help** tab. There is option of **"Documentation and API Reference"**.

Comment: you can no longer download documentations?

Comment: I also have only option for **Guide and sample code**  in component tab.